# Nucleophilicity and basicity of compounds with or without nitrogen inversion

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, conformers, nucleophilicity

In nitrogen inversion, the lone pair changes its direction continuously.

Does this in any way delocalize the charge density on the nitrogen making it less nucleophilic and less basic than, say, a bridgehead nitrogen?

Consider the specific case of quinuclidine and triethylamine. Which will be more nucleophilic among them and why?

[image]

Comment: Related, maybe almost a duplicate, but not quite as it doesn't ask about nucleophilicity: [Does nitrogen inversion affect the basicity of amines?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/38749/16683)

Comment: related to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38749/does-amine-inversion-affect-basic-strength

Comment: @orthocresol yes, I read that. Didn't find the answer too satisfying. It is too vague.

Comment: @user226375 I have the same question too. Even in electrostatic maps the negative charges looks like its located above the nitrogen but no density below. Have you find an answer?

Comment: Idk why this was overlooked, but please note that quinuclidine does NOT have a bridge head carbon. The bridge head atom is a nitrogen atom.